# Can't display french symbols in android application

Tags: java, android, json, encoding

Hello i have problems displaying french symbols in my application. I have recieved a json file that i have to organize and display in my application but the problem is that the french symbols are displayed as question marks or are displayed as a white space. The json file is in asci format. I tried to read it with different encoding options in my application but i can't get it to display the correct letters. I know this is maybe a basic question and i have read a lot of resources but still im unable to solve the problem. Someone please help me This is the json file i have received http://www.mediafire.com/download/f4mh61bm4p2cu79/french.json Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
public static void parseJson1(Context mCtx, int resId) {

    JsonReader jsonReader = null;
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        iStream = mCtx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));

        jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);

        jsonReader.beginObject();
        //jsonReader.setLenient(true);
        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

            String name = jsonReader.nextName();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("status")) {

                String statusValue = jsonReader.nextString();
                if (statusValue.equals("success")) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    break;
                }

            } else if (name.equals("data")) {
                jsonReader.beginObject();

                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

                    String books = jsonReader.nextName();
                    if (books.equals("books")) {

                        jsonReader.beginArray();
                        int bookId = 1;
                        int chapterId = 1;
                        int verseId = 0;

                        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                            // chapters
                            jsonReader.beginObject();
                            Book book = new Book();
                            book.setId(bookId);

                            while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

                                String tokenName = jsonReader.nextName();
                                if (tokenName.equals("chapters")) {

                                    jsonReader.beginArray();
                                    List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<Chapter>();
                                    while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

                                        jsonReader.beginObject();
                                        Chapter chapter = new Chapter();
                                        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

                                            String chapterKeys = jsonReader
                                                    .nextName();
                                            if (chapterKeys
                                                    .equals("chapter_name")) {

                                                //String chapterName = jsonReader
                                                    //  .nextString();

                                                String test11 = new String(jsonReader
                                                        .nextString().getBytes("CP-1252"));
                                                chapter.setName(test11);

                                            } else if (chapterKeys
                                                    .equals("chapter_id")) {
                                                int chaprId = jsonReader
                                                        .nextInt();
                                                chapter.setId(chapterId);
                                            } else if (chapterKeys
                                                    .equals("verses")) {

                                                ++chapterId;

                                                jsonReader.beginArray();

                                                List<Verse> vesrsList = new ArrayList<Verse>();

                                                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {

                                                    jsonReader
                                                            .beginObject();
                                                    Verse verse = new Verse();

                                                    while (jsonReader
                                                            .hasNext()) {

                                                        String verseKeys = jsonReader
                                                                .nextName();
                                                        if (verseKeys
                                                                .equals("verse_text")) {
                                                            try{
                                                            String test11 = new String(jsonReader
                                                                    .nextString().getBytes("CP-1252"));
                                                            verse.setContent(test11);

                                                            }
                                                            catch(Exception e){
                                                                String verseTxt = jsonReader
                                                                        .nextString();
                                                                verse.setContent(verseTxt);
                                                            }


                                                        } else if (verseKeys
                                                                .equals("verse_id")) {
                                                            int versionId = jsonReader
                                                                    .nextInt();

                                                            verse.setId(versionId);
                                                        } else if (verseKeys
                                                                .equals("verse_number")) {
                                                            int verseNumber = jsonReader
                                                                    .nextInt();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    jsonReader.endObject();
                                                    verse.setChapterId(chapterId);
                                                    vesrsList.add(verse);

                                                }

                                                Verse.insert(vesrsList);
                                                jsonReader.endArray();
                                            } else if (chapterKeys
                                                    .equals("chapter_number")) {
                                                int chapterNumber = jsonReader
                                                        .nextInt();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        jsonReader.endObject();
                                        // end object
                                        chapter.setBookId(bookId);
                                        chapterList.add(chapter);

                                    }

                                    Chapter.insert(chapterList);
                                    jsonReader.endArray();

                                } else if (tokenName.equals("book_name")) {
                                    //String bookName = jsonReader
                                        //  .nextString();
                                    String test11 = new String(jsonReader
                                            .nextString().getBytes("CP-1252"));
                                    book.setName(test11);
                                } else if (tokenName
                                        .equals("is_new_testament")) {
                                    String isNewTestiment = jsonReader
                                            .nextBoolean() ? "true"
                                            : "false";
                                    /*String isNewTestiment = jsonReader
                                            .nextString() ;*/
                                    book.setNewTestament(isNewTestiment);
                                } else if (tokenName
                                        .equals("book_name_english_char")) {
                                    String bookEngChar = jsonReader
                                            .nextString();
                                    book.setNameEngChar(bookEngChar);
                                } else if (tokenName.equals("book_id")) {
                                    int bkId = jsonReader.nextInt();
                                } else if (tokenName.equals("book_number")) {
                                    int bkNo = jsonReader.nextInt();
                                }
                            }
                            // save the book info and get the book id
                            bookId = book.save();
                            jsonReader.endObject();
                            ++bookId;

                        }
                        jsonReader.endArray();
                    }
                }
                jsonReader.endObject();
            }
        }
        jsonReader.endObject();

    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (jsonReader != null) {
            try {
                jsonReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (iStream != null) {
            try {
                iStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            iStream = null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should post the code that you used for parsing and display for people to help you.

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't think it was necessary in this case, will paste it now

Comment: do you mean that you are getting some "?" instead of symbols?

Comment: Yes im getting the question mark but when i put the cp-1252 i get a blank or  spot

Comment: `.getBytes("CP-1252")` why?

Comment: `The json file is in asci format` no it is not. ascii does not handle accents.

Comment: your json file is encoded using whichever 8-bit encoding that handles accents. could be cp-1252 or iso, does not make much difference. You need to specify that encoding when creating the inputstreamreader

Comment: i thought that would be the appropriate encoding for the file

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"UTF-8"` encoding, defining an `unicodeReader`:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(new UnicodeReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: unlikely. `utf-8` is the default encoding on the android platform. always better to explicitly set it though.

Comment: the actual encoding of the file is probably cp-1252, so that would be the encoding to set in the inputstream reader. Also what is this `unicodereader`  in this context?

Comment: yeah it worked as you said i just had to put the encoding on the input stream to cp-1252 and not on the json text where i have been putting it, Now that i look into it of course it should go there since that is the part where the text is encode and later i was encoding the already encoded text, So obvious now... Thanks for your help